# Properties of $k[a+b,c+d] \subseteq k[a,b,c,d]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $D$ be a commutative $k$-algebra which is an integral domain, $k$ a field of characteristic zero.
Let $a,b,c,d \in D$.

Assume that $I:= \langle a+b,c+d \rangle=\langle a,b,c,d \rangle$ (ideals in $D$).

> Is there something 'interesting' to say about $k[a+b,c+d] \subseteq k[a,b,c,d] \subseteq D$?

Truly, I do not see how exactly $\langle a+b,c+d \rangle=\langle a,b,c,d \rangle$ may help, but anyway I wish to assume this.

What is we will consider the ideal in $k[a,b,c,d]$ generated by $a,b,c,d$?

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: The question is rather vague. What would you consider to be "interesting"? Have you looked at any examples?

Comment: Thank you, I agree I should have elaborated more. 'Interesting', for example, may mean: flat; integral; algebraic etc. Only the trivial example $b=d=0$, in which $k[a+b,c+d]=k[a,b,c,d]$ of course..

Comment: It seems that equality of algebras also holds for an automorphism of $k[x,y]$: $(x,y) \mapsto (a+b,c+d)$. For example, $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y+x^2)$ with $a=x,b=0,c=y,d=x^2$. Indeed, $\langle x,y+x^2 \rangle= \langle x,y,x^2 \rangle= \langle x,y \rangle$ and $k[x,y+x^2]=k[x,y,x^2]=k[x,y]$.